# XCode 12.3 building for iOS Simulator, but linking in dylib built for iOS, couchbaselite framework for architecture arm64 Using M1 Chipset

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, nativescript, xcode12, couchbase-lite

Encountered a build issue on IOS too with "building for iOS Simulator, but linking in dylib built for iOS, file '.../platforms/ios/Pods/CouchbaseLite/iOS/CouchbaseLite.framework/CouchbaseLite' for architecture arm64"

I currently using nativescript 6.5.3 and cocoapod 1.10.
Using M1 chipset.

Comment: Same boat: 
I'm on circleci - cocoapods 10.1, builds for simulator (same error)
"building for iOS, but linking in dylib file ... built for iOS Simulator"

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to **TARGET** (e.g. `Runner` in my screen, not the **PROJECT**), then **Build Settings**
2. Search for `excluded` like in screenshot.
3. Edit the field in `Architectures` > `Excluded Architectures`, to add `arm64`. You can double click the top line to edit all 3 lines below.
4. Rebuild/ run

[image: Screenshot of IDE showing architectures section which contains exluded architectures subsection, which as Debug, Profile, Release subsections. Edit all of them to contain arm64]

My details: Running on M1 mac mini, with a flutter iOS project.

Answer (score 3):

Since Xcode is a Universal Application, You can make Xcode to use the intel based logic even in the m1 mac mini for a quick fix and then try to find the cause and fix it if you can:

0. Quit Xcode.
1. Right-click on Xcode.app (the application itself! **NOT** the one in the dock and **NOT** the project file)
2. Select Get info.
3. Select "Open using Rosetta" or "Open using Rosetta 2"
4. Launch Xcode and Run your project.

[image: Xcode get info example]